# Error when transferring Sysprep to OOBE mode

Tags: windows, sysprep, oobe

Error when transferring Sysprep to OOBE mode

```
2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error                 SYSPRP Package Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackru-RU_17763.32.110.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image. 

2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2. 

2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2. 

2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2 
2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2 
2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating Sysprep session actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2 
2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2 
2023-06-15 11:15:11, Error      [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2 
2023-06-15 11:15:12, Info       [0x0f0052] SYSPRP Shutting down SysPrep log 
2023-06-15 11:15:12, Info       [0x0f004d] SYSPRP The time is now 2023-06-15 11:15:12
```

Does anyone know the command to delete this pack?

Tried the command in PowerShell:

```bash
Dism.exe /Image:C:\MountImage /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackru-RU_17763.32.110.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Here's what it writes in response:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Dism.exe /Image:C:\MountImage /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackru-RU_17763.32.110.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe  

System DISM  
Version: 10.0.17763.3406  


Mistake: 2  

Failed to access the image.
Make sure that the path to the image and the Windows directory of the image exist and the account has rights to read the folder.

The DISM log file is located at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```